# document.getElementsBy is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube-api

I want to create my first Firefox-Addon so I am really inexperienced.
I want to create an Addon, to modify the YouTube-Website.

background.js

```
    function editVideo() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2;
    document.getElementById("movie_player").stopVideo();
    document.getElementById("movie_player").setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
    document.getElementById("movie_player").playVideo();
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(editVideo);
```

manifest.json

```
{

  "description": "YouTube-Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "YouTube-Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "icons/logo_48.png",
      "64": "icons/logo_64.png"
    }
  }

}
```

So if I click the Button, the Playbackrate should be 2 and the quality 720p.
But nothing happens! If I type thoose commands directly into the console, it works.

I always get this error:

> document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined

or:

> document.getElementById(...) is null

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add the html code please? This should not happen usually.

Comment: Could you paste you html code as well please?

Comment: well I know with chrome, you need to set it up in your manifest you are working with the content, my guess is firefox is probably the same way.

Comment: Those responses indicate that the DOM is not loaded at the time of the calls.

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly do you mean with html code? The HTML-Code from YouTube?

Comment: You are probably trying to get the data in `index.js` or `background.js`, but what you really want is to create a `contentscript.js`

Comment: @Pavlo I tried to rename it to contentscript.js and change it also in the manifest.json but I still get the same error.

Comment: Post your code....

Comment: @epascarello This is my whole code. I have two files. manifest.json and background.js. I posted my whole background.js

Comment: So what is the manifest code look like?

Comment: @epascarello Edit: I posted the manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "description": "YouTube-Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "YouTube-Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
          "js": ["runsOnWebPage.js"],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
      }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "icons/logo_48.png",
      "64": "icons/logo_64.png"
    }
  }
}
```

The js file within the content_scripts should now run on youtube, you might want to add more `"matches"` since this one only covers that specific link, and youtube has like 1000 different links

Comment: Thank you. I don't get this error Messag anymore, but it still doesn't work. Nothing happens. And what do I have to write in the background.js file now can I let it emtpy?

Comment: Are you putting the JS file in the content script? Maybe it has something to do with permissions, also try to console log outside the function before the browser action

Comment: Yes, I put the whole code in the runsOnWebPage.js. I let the background.js empty. And I don't get any error messages in the console-log.

Comment: If you press F12 on youtube, do you see what you logged?

Comment: I get this on the console-log:
Laden fehlgeschlagen für das <script> mit der Quelle "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_companion_ad.js".
Laden fehlgeschlagen für das <script> mit der Quelle "https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js".
Laden fehlgeschlagen für das <script> mit der Quelle "https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js".
"Laden fehlgeschlagen" means that the content wasn't load. This is because I am using Pi-Hole and this will block google-ads

Comment: This doesn't look like your script, go to content script page and try to copy paste from there.

Comment: I guess you mean this: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/180216/5z89y6c5.png
Before I was using runsOnWebPage.js there was the error. Not there is no error.

Comment: Is this your console, try to navigate around you might find the script

Comment: Yes it is my console. And I found the problem. browser.browserAction is undefined
Because I can't use this outside of background.js How can I start the runsOnWebPage.js automatically?

Comment: When do you want the event to fire, which button are you talking about?